# Rails 7 with Bootstrap 5 - Cursor Not Changing to Pointer After Page Reload in Firefox and Safari

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-5, import-maps

I am experiencing a peculiar issue in my Rails 7 application with Bootstrap installed via import maps. This issue is happening only on Firefox and Safari; it works as expected on Chrome.

Here is the problem:

When I hover over a link, the cursor turns into a pointer, as expected. However, if I click on the link, causing the page to reload, and don't move the mouse cursor, it doesn't turn back into a pointer. Then if I move the pointer I can move it to any of the ul links in the navbar and it doesn't change to the hand pointer. If I move off the link onto the main page, then back to the link, the pointer turns into a hand pointer correctly.

The same issue occurs when I hover over the link and then manually refresh the browser. I need to move the mouse off the link and back on for the cursor to change back into a pointer.

[image: showing pointer behavior after clicking]

I have tried various solutions such as:

```
1. Applying css cursor: pointer !important; to the anchor tags.
2. Disabling Turbo for the specific links.
3. Triggering a mouseleave event on page load in js.
4. Ensuring no other CSS rules are overriding cursor: pointer;.
5. Disabling all browser extensions.
```

Despite these efforts, the issue still persists.

I'm using the default bootstrap navbar example from here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

im my importmaps.rb"

```
pin "bootstrap", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.esm.js"
pin "@popperjs/core", to: "https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/esm/index.js"
```

Bootstrap all seems to work apart from this issue, and it actually does work in chrome.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any suggestions on what else I could try?

Thank you for your help!